# Uso de ListBox para visualizar archivos de directorios - Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-c++

Soy nuevo utilizando Visual C++, y necesito saber como visualizar los archivos de un directorio usando ListBox en Visual c++.
Espero me puedan ayudar, de antemano gracias.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298372(v=vs.85).aspx, sigue ese link, tal vez pueda servirte

Answer (score 0):

Envia el mensaje LB_DIR cuando crees el ListBox:

```
HWND lbHWnd;    // Este es el handle que se obtuvo al crear el ListBox con CreateWindowEx

SendMessage(lbHWnd, LB_DIR, DDL_READWRITE | DDL_READONLY | DDL_HIDDEN
            | DDL_SYSTEM | DDL_DIRECTORY | DDL_ARCHIVE | DDL_DRIVES, (LPARAM)TEXT("*.*"));
```

Los flags tipo DDL_ especifican que archivos se filtraran en el ListBox.

Los archivos que se visualizarán en el ListBox son los correspondientes al directorio en el que se ejecuta el programa..para especificar otro llama a la función:

```
SetCurrentDirectory(LPCSTR directorio_a_examinar);
```

Espero sea de ayuda...